# Magento Admin Error Cannot find Zend_Http_Header

Tags: magento-1.9

```
Class 'Zend_Http_Header_HeaderValue' not found in /lib/Zend/Http/Response.php on line 532
```

I got this error when accessingmy magento admin. Anyone got this error? and how did you manage to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your Zend library seems to be corrupt.

- Magento CE 1.9.2.1 ships with *[ZF 1.12.10](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/releases/tag/release-1.12.10)*.
- Magento CE 1.9.2.2 ships with *[ZF 1.12.16](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/releases/tag/release-1.12.16)*.

It looks like parts of your library are up to date (`Zend_Http_Response`) while others are not (`Zend_Http_Header_HeaderValue` missing, available since *ZF 1.12.12*).

Depending on your Magento patch number (*.1 or *.2), replace the `/lib/Zend` directory with the corresponding ZF version mentioned above in order to re-establish the library's version integrity.